# How to only get notifications when your name is tagged in a work item's comment in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

**REQUIREMENT/CASE:**

In `Azure Devops` I do not want to get notified about comments in a `Work Item` where I am not tagged. In other words I only want to get notified by email when my name is tagged in a comment.

**QUESTION:**

How can one achieve that in `Notification Settings` in `Azure Devops` creating a new `Notification` subscription?

**EXPECTING:**

I would be glad if someone can present a screenshot of how a `Notification Subscription` should look like to solve the above presented case.

Comment: When someone tag your name you get an email automatically, you don't need to configure it.

Comment: @ Jagjit Singh Shayki is correct, you will get an email automatically if some tag your name in comments. Please describe your scenario, if you get unexpected notification.